# Vba issue in copying rows from multiple worksheets based on searching dynamic value and paste it in another new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub multiple()

    Workbooks("A.xlsx").Activate
    lastRow11 = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow11 To 1 Step -1

        If i <> "" Then

            Value = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "I").Value
            Workbooks("B.xlsx").Activate
            Worksheets(1).Select

            Set DynRange = Selection.Find(What:=Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
          MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If DynRange Is Nothing Then
                 MsgBox ("No codes found")
            Else
                cell.EntireRow.Copy
                Workbooks.Add
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

In the above-mentioned code, I am trying to search the `"DynRange"` value (that is dynamic every time) in workbook B. The purpose is to copy the rows for which particular column is having those values from all the worksheets of workbook B and paste it to a new workbook. 
If worksheet B has 5 worksheets the new workbook should have 5 worksheets respectively. But data in those 5 worksheets must be filtered according to the `"DynRange"` value.

Also, for the next `"DynRange"` value. The new workbook should be added and the rest of the process should be the same.

How can i optimize performing this task? My code is not working as expected.

Comment: Apart from `cell.EntireRow.Copy` giving an "object required" error (which is an obvious problem) what do you mean by "is not responding as expected"?

Comment: Whatever value I am getting in DynRange, It is being present in multiple times in workbook B but I am getting only first occurrence of that row, I want all the occurrences like finding all rows having that particular value.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for finding all matches:

```
If DynRange Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox ("No codes found")
Endif
Do While Not DynRange Is Nothing
     'process here the recent hit
     Set Fnd = Selection.FindNext(DynRange)
Loop
```

If I understand your needs correctly you want to process all worksheets in B.xlsx, but you only refer to Worksheet(1). 
I would avoid using .Selection. 
You may also consider `Sheets.Add` instead of `Workbooks.Add`.

Comment: Thanks but still not getting the desired output.